# Sendmail with yahoo as domain with empty subject and recipient address

Tags: linux, openssl, sendmail, busybox

1. /usr/sbin/sendmail -c smtp.mail.yahoo.com -p 465 -f test@yahoo.com 
   guest@gmail.com -s hellostack -k /tmp/sendmail.cnt -autest -appassword -H openssl s_client -connect smtp.mail.yahoo.com:465 -amtls1
2. When i am sending email using gmail subject is sending correctly, where as when i am using from address with yahoo credentials Subject and To address is empty.
   Please see the attachment
3. Is there any other way for sending for yahoo using sendmail for getting subject and recipients[image] correctly

Comment: Are you SURE your sendmail version supports ALL command line options you have used?  Check `man sendmail`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Which package provides `sendmail` executable file (`/usr/sbin/sendmail`) on you computer?